# If photons don't have charge, why are they deflected by charged black holes?

Tags: black-holes, photons

If photons don't have charge, why are they deflected by charged black holes?

According to [quantum electrodynamics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_electrodynamics), photons don't have electric or magnetic fields either.

Comment: Are you sure that photons are deflected by the *charge* of the black hole and not due to the *curvature* of the spacetime near the black hole?

Comment: @KyleKanos yes i am sure, photons do not have charge, they are deflected differently by black holes than by non-charged ones. charge does affect the photon trajectory.

Comment: @johnson then, better add charge contribution in question.

Comment: @johnson316: The [charged black hole has a different metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reissner–Nordström_metric#The_metric) than an [uncharged one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_metric#The_Schwarzschild_metric).

Answer (score 1):

The photon is not deflected by the charge. It's deflected by the spacetime curvature.

The spacetime curvature is related to the [stress-energy tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor) (by [Einstein's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_field_equations)), so if you change the stress-energy tensor you change the curvature. A static black hole, described by a Schwarzschild metric, has a very simple stress-energy tensor since it's effectively a [point mass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor#Isolated_particle). The stress-energy tensor is everywhere zero except at the singularity where only $T_{00}$ is non-zero, and that's a delta function.

If you now add charge then the resulting electric field [also contributes to the stress-energy tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor). In fact the contribution to the stress-energy tensor is non-zero everywhere the field is non-zero. This changes the curvature (to the [Reissner-Nordström metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reissner%E2%80%93Nordstr%C3%B6m_metric)) and indeed it's the reason why a second horizon exists in charged black holes. In effect the contribution to the stress-energy tensor outside the event horizon opposes the contribution due to the mass at the centre. If the field is strong enough the horizon will disappear leaving a naked singularity.

So the photon is not interacting with the charge, just the curvature.